# Translate picklist value in PageBlock title

Tags: visualforce, pageblock, translation

We are using

```
<apex:pageBlock title="{account.MyField__c}">
```

where **MyField** is a picklist with the corresponding translations. The problem is that the picklist value is not translated to the user's language. From [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SvOnAAK) I found that including raw picklist fields in VF doesn't get translated and that we should use **apex:outputField**. But I can't find a way of using it inside the pageBlock title attribute.

Any ideas on how to get the translation inside the title?

Comment: Based on that doc, you won't be able to do it per se; probably the "easiest" workaround is to render a hidden outputField and then use JS/jQuery magic to stuff into the page block title.

Comment: Based on the issue you linked this has been fixed.  I'd suggest contacting SFDC support and letting them know you're still experiencing the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, the Known Issues page is incorrect. The issue has not been fixed. I've brought it to the attention of the page owner.

Comment: @Carolyn, could you please post your comment as the answer to the question unless you have updated information?

Comment: @crmprogdev I don't have any update, other than that the Known Issues page has been corrected now. I actually think jkraybill's response is a more likely answer, though I haven't tried it to see.

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Account.MyField__c.getDescribe(); 
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> P = F.getPicklistValues(); 
Map<String, String> mapMyFieldTranslation = new Map<String, String>(); 

for(Schema.PicklistEntry e : P){
    mapMyFieldTranslation.put(e.value, e.label); 
}

String result = mapMyFieldTranslation.get(myAccount.MyField__c));
```

With 'result' containing the translation.